# How to inject keyboard events in Google Chrome with Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard

I am trying to simulate keyboard shortcuts on gmail.com in Google Chrome using javscript, but I failed. I am new to javascript and programming in general, I have tried different snippets of code and attempted many time, without any success. here is the code

```
var b=document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
if (b.initKeyboardEvent) {
        b.initKeyboardEvent("keydown", true, true, document.defaultView, false, false, false, false, 191, 191);
    } else {
        b.initKeyEvent("keydown", true, true, document.defaultView, false, false, false, false, 191, 0);
    }
```

Now this should trigger the "/" key and focus the search, as planned by Gmail shortcuts, but it doesn't work. Currently I am using the Google Chrome console for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to programmatically trigger input keys in the sandboxed browser environment under normal circumstances. This is a security feature to stop code from interacting with the browser as if it were a real person.

Comment: So this is impossible? Is there any way detect the code of a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can log every keystroke but that won't tell you what shortcut it is triggering. You can view a list of gmail shortcuts here https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?hl=en

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I meant if there was a possibility to perform the actions triggered by the shortcut in another way, for example by clicking a button.